# A RenderAnimatedOpacity expected a child of type RenderBox but received a child of type RenderSliverList

Tags: flutter

I want to render the result list of `SearchDelegate` in flutter ,When I am render a silver list in context like this:

```
@override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    var channelRequest = new ChannelRequest();
    channelRequest.name = query;
    channelRequest.pageNum = 1;
    channelRequest.pageSize = 10;

    return FutureBuilder(
        future: ChannelAction.searchChannel(channelRequest),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<Channel> post = snapshot.data;
            if (post != null) {
              return SliverList(delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
                return Slidable();
              }));
            }
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        });
  }
```

shows this error:

```
A RenderAnimatedOpacity expected a child of type RenderBox but received a child of type RenderSliverList.

RenderObjects expect specific types of children because they coordinate with their children during layout and paint. For example, a RenderSliver cannot be the child of a RenderBox because a RenderSliver does not understand the RenderBox layout protocol.
The RenderAnimatedOpacity that expected a RenderBox child was created by: FadeTransition ← KeyedSubtree-[<1>] ← Stack ← AnimatedSwitcher ← _BodyBuilder ← MediaQuery ← LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.body>] ← CustomMultiChildLayout ← AnimatedBuilder ← DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ← _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#ab4b5 ink renderer] ← ⋯
The RenderSliverList that did not match the expected child type was created by: SliverList ← FutureBuilder<List<Channel>> ← KeyedSubtree-[<_SearchBody.results>] ← FadeTransition ← KeyedSubtree-[<1>] ← Stack ← AnimatedSwitcher ← _BodyBuilder ← MediaQuery ← LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.body>] ← CustomMultiChildLayout ← AnimatedBuilder ← ⋯
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  FutureBuilder<List<Channel>> file:///Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/lib/src/common/search.dart:43:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      RenderObjectWithChildMixin.debugValidateChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2977:9)
#1      RenderObjectWithChildMixin.debugValidateChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3004:6)
#2      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.insertRenderObjectChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6132:25)
#3      RenderObjectElement.attachRenderObject (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5805:35)
#4      RenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5501:5)
...
```

what should I do to fix it?

Comment: I have the same problem, do you found any solution?

Comment: yes, I finally change my code and finally solve this problem. @KőneMátyás

Answer (score 1):

A **sliver** is a portion of a scrollable area which produces **RenderSliver** object. The solution would be to wrap SliverList with CustomScrollView.

For anyone experiencing the same issue, changing the code to the one below might help:

```
  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    var channelRequest = new ChannelRequest();
    channelRequest.name = query;
    channelRequest.pageNum = 1;
    channelRequest.pageSize = 10;

    return FutureBuilder(
        future: ChannelAction.searchChannel(channelRequest),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<Channel> post = snapshot.data;
            if (post != null) {
              return CustomScrollView(
                  slivers: [
                    SliverList(
                      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
                        return Slidable();
                      })),
                  ],
                );
            }
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        });
  }
```